# Cortisol in Generalized Anxiety Disorder: is there a consensus?

Tags: stress, anxiety, aging

I've seen some recent papers that find elevated cortisol in GAD patients, particularly in older ones, and that [SSRI medication lowers cortisol in such GAD patients](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3424606/). However I also found [an older study](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0165-1781(91)90021-G) that didn't find any difference in cortisol between GAD and controls.

So is there some consensus on the correlation between cortisol and GAD? Is age the primary moderating factor in this correlation?